# Is it possible to retrieve a set of files from a Git repository at their initial state

Tags: git, initialization, commit

I have a git repository with many (`.tex`) files that have been added at different times/commits. I'd like to copy in a temporary directory all of them as they were at their initial state (when they were added to the repository). The point is to show to somebody how ugly they look before some work has been done on them :)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible, but by the time it's done you may wish you'd just picked a few samples to extract manually.

So first off, you need to identify "first versions of files".  The simplest way I can think to do that is with `git log` - which is not great for scripting, but...

```
git log --diff-filter=A --name-only --format=' :COMMIT: %H' --all -- *.tex **/*.tex
```

The format string starts with something you reasonably expect would not be part of a file path.  I've added some pathspec arguments to the end, which should limit the output to only show `.tex` files.  This is probably the more efficient of two ways this could be done; but in case it causes problems, I'll mention an alternative in the script below...

Now you have a list of commits.  For each commit you see the commit ID (hash) followed by a list of files created in the commit.

So you can process that output using whatever kind of script you like.  I use perl for this kind of things, so it'd be something like

```
my $sha = 0;
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  next if m/^$/;
  if ( m/^ :COMMIT: ([0-9a-f]*)$/ ) {
    $sha = $1;
  } else {
    system("git --work-tree=/path/to/temp/dir checkout $sha -- $_");
  }
}
```

Note that if adding path arguments to the initial `git log` command didn't work - or you otherwise chose not to do that - you could change the `else` to an `elsif` like this:

```
my $sha = 0;
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  next if m/^$/;
  if ( m/^ :COMMIT: ([0-9a-f]*)$/ ) {
    $sha = $1;
  } elsif ( m/\.tex$/ ) {
    system("git --work-tree=/path/to/temp/dir checkout $sha -- $_");
  }
}
```

If you want to include the `git log` command in the perl script, that would look like this:

```
my $sha = 0;
my @list = `git log --diff-filter=A --name-only --format=' :COMMIT: %H' --all -- *.tex **/*.tex`;
foreach(@list) {
  chomp;
  next if m/^$/;
  if ( m/^ :COMMIT: ([0-9a-f]*)$/ ) {
    $sha = $1;
  } elsif ( m/\.tex$/ ) {
    system("git --work-tree=/path/to/temp/dir checkout $sha -- $_");
  }
}
```

Comment: In your first code, I guess the back quote after `%H` should be a (normal) quote. Apart from this, your solution seems to work but, unfortunately, catches too much files: I'd like to restrict it to `.tex` files only.

Comment: Fixed the quote, and added some options to filter out non-`.tex` files.

Comment: Works nicely. Could be better if everything would be gathered in the Perl script, instead of piping it on the first command :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first find the commit when they were first added to the repository, to do that, you can run:

```
git log <PATH_TO_YOUR_FILES> | tail
```

Now copy (part of) the commit hash written on top of the commit message

```
commit 4adbcaf93a0805fd2c6fbcb6b929c3d438ce7c07
```

You can now get the file as it was in that commit by running:

```
git cat-file -p 4adbcaf:<PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE>
```

---

Put together, you can restore a set of files to their state as in their initial commit using a bash script like this:

```
# git-restore-initial-state.sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p temp
for f in "$@"
do
  commit=$(git log --pretty=%H "$f" | tail -1)
  git cat-file -p "$commit:$f" > "temp/$f"
done
```

Save the script and run it:

```
git-restore-initial-state.sh file_a file_b
```

---

Edit: Thanks to [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) for his help in simplifying the script.

Comment: That's how to copy *one* of them to the work tree.  OP asked for a way to copy *all* of them to a temp directory.  Picking a few samples to do this way may be a better use of time, but it doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thanks Mark, I see your point, edited with a script that does the work of restoring a set of files, copying to a temp directory and restoring them back to their HEAD state

Comment: @MahdiDibaiee May I give some tips to improve your script? `git log --pretty=%H -- path_to_file` can get all the commits that change this file. `git cat-file -p commit:path_to_file` can print the content of the file of the commit. So you can use these two commands to make the script simpler.

Comment: The `git cat-file -p "$commit:$f" > "temp/$f"` command leads to the error `fatal: Not a valid object name ⟨the commit⟩:⟨the file⟩`

Comment: @DenisBitouzé can you please share the exact command you executed? Might help to debug the script. I've already tested it on a dummy repository but might be an edge case. On a side note, have you tried to manually find the commits for your files to see if it succeeds?

Comment: @MahdiDibaiee I executed `f=test.tex`, then `commit=$(git log --pretty=%H "$f" | tail -1)` and then `git cat-file -p "$commit:$f" > "temp/$f"` (here the error message). About the side note, I guess it's okay since, with the previous commands, `echo $commit` returns the corresponding commit ID.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I guess that's because you are not executing the commands in the root of your git repository, is that the case? If so that might be a reason why "$commit:$f" can't be found (`Not a valid object name`)

Answer (score 0):

To get the first commit ID/desc of every file (with ".tex"):

```
for f in *.tex; do git log --oneline "$f" | tail -1; done
```

You can view the initial commit full msg by using something like:

```
for f in *.tex; do git show $(git log --oneline "$f" | tail -1 | awk '{print$1}'); done
```

to copy out your initial files in a temp directory you can use the next script:

```
$ mkdir ../temp
$ ls *.tex > ../temp/listOfFiles.txt
$ cat ../temp/listOfFiles.txt | while read line; do git checkout $(git log --oneline "$line" | tail -1 | awk '{print$1}'); cp "$line" ../temp/"$line"; git checkout master; done
$ git status
```

at the end the repo is in the last state.. hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting the same files in the `temp` directory as the current version in the Git repository.

Comment: I have done just now a second test and is working fine for me.. make sure your repo is updated